# PUBG Texture isnt loading

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

So when I drop out of the plane the houses and everything is blury . It takes like 1 minute or 2 to load which by that time I would be dead . I have set everything on very low .
SPECS : 
GTX 950 OC
I5 4590 3.30ghz
8 GB RAM

Comment: Got a screenshot on hand/

Comment: Keep in mind that at the time of this post, the game is also in early access, which basically makes anything we answer here able to be updated quickly.

Comment: This smells of you not having your graphics set up properly. Make sure your computer knows to use your graphics card as the default rendering hardware (and that your monitor is plugged in to the graphics card), and that you have up-to-date drivers.

Comment: I have this issue consistently, the only fix is to wait for the devs to optimise building loading. Other possible ways around it are upping render distance so they load in faster or pressing tab, it crashes your game until the buildings finish loading, but it seems to speed the process up a little

Comment: Is it just blurry textures, or are thing like trees, houses, and fences really blobby and misshapen? If so, it sounds like it takes a while for your computer to load in the different levels of detail for the different models. I have a similar issue with my machine. Try googling around for lowest quality Model LOD, and rendering issues.

Comment: https://www.google.me/search?q=pubg+texture+load+bug&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx-Oex8s_UAhVIChoKHQKxCDYQ_AUICygC&biw=1920&bih=974#imgrc=8Ci8zVEGzvnSGM:               This isn't my picture but this is what it looks like

Comment: Do you have an SSD? A friend of mine has the same problem, and he's the only one out of 6 People who doesn't have an SSD.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the process priority from Normal to High helped me with this bug.

Windows 7 :

```
Task Manager > Processes > TslGame.exe > Set Priority > High
```

Windows 10 :

```
Task Manager > Details > TslGame.exe > Set Priority > High
```

You can also use the following code to set a current PUBG process to High Priority :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// #define DEBUG

namespace ProcessRealtime
{
    class PUBG_RealTime
    {
        static string processName = "TslGame";
        static ProcessPriorityClass newPriority = ProcessPriorityClass.High;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG
            PutDebug("Start!");
#endif
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
#if DEBUG
            PutDebug(processes.Length + " processed found");
#endif
            foreach (Process proc in processes)
            {
#if DEBUG
                PutDebug("New process found");
#endif
                Console.WriteLine("Changing Priority for id:" + proc.Id + " to " + newPriority.ToString());
                proc.PriorityClass = newPriority;
#if DEBUG
                PutDebug("Changed priority for " + proc.Id);
#endif
            }
#if DEBUG
            PutDebug("No more processes..");
#endif
            Console.Write("Press a key, it's over !");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

#if DEBUG
        static bool debug = true;
        static int debugInc = 1;
        static void PutDebug(string info = "")
        {
            if(debug){
                Console.WriteLine("Debug" + debugInc + ": " + info);
                debugInc++;
            }
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

Or you can use the next code to start PUBG directly on High Priority (just parameterize your Steam location in the code) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProcessRealtime
{
    class StartPUBG_RealTime
    {
        static string steamLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Steam";
        static string steamExe = "steam.exe";
        static string gameId = "578080";
        static string fullExe = "\"" + steamLocation + @"\"+ steamExe + "\"";
        static string parameters = "steam://rungameid/" + gameId;
        static string steamInfo = fullExe + " " + parameters;
        static string processName = "TslGame";
        static ProcessPriorityClass newPriority = ProcessPriorityClass.High;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PutDebug("Starting Game");
            Process pubgProcess = new Process();
            try
            {
                pubgProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                pubgProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fullExe;
                pubgProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters;
                pubgProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                PutDebug(steamInfo);
                pubgProcess.Start();
                Process[] processes = new Process[0];
                PutDebug("Start search for process!");
                while(processes.Length == 0){
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    PutDebug("Searching process..");
                    processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
                }
                foreach (Process proc in processes)
                {
                    PutDebug("Changing process priority for " + proc.Id);
                    proc.PriorityClass = newPriority;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        static bool debug = true;
        static int debugInc = 1;
        static void PutDebug(string info = "")
        {
            if(debug){
                Console.WriteLine("Debug" + debugInc + ": " + info);
                debugInc++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I did this before  but when I went to check it out again it was set back to normal . It helped only for first match then second it came back.

Comment: You have to do it everytime you launch the game. If you wish to have it as high priority each time you launch the game you will have to make your own launcher (`start` cmd implements priorities)

Comment: Also, this is not magical, the game is not very performent, so you will have also to wait until the game is fully operational